# File Upload to server issues in Android

Tags: android, file-upload, httpurlconnection

i have code for file uploading to server its code working individual but this implemented in my app its goto exception all the time

here is my code

```
 public int uploadFile(String sourceFileUri) {
    String fileName = sourceFileUri;

    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    DataOutputStream dos = null;
    String lineEnd = "\r\n";
    String twoHyphens = "--";
    String boundary = "*****";
    int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
    byte[] buffer;
    int maxBufferSize = 1 * 1024 * 1024;
    File sourceFile = new File(sourceFileUri);

    if (!sourceFile.isFile()) {

       // dialog.dismiss();

        Log.e("uploadFile", "Source File not exist :"
                + selectedFilePath);

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
              //  messageText.setText("Source File not exist :"
                      //  + selectedFilePath);
            }
        });

        return 0;

    } else {
        int serverResponseCode = 0;

        try {

            // open a URL connection to the Servlet
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(sourceFile);
            URL url = new URL(uploadurl);

            // Open a HTTP  connection to  the URL
            conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setDoInput(true); // Allow Inputs
            conn.setDoOutput(true); // Allow Outputs
            conn.setUseCaches(false); // Don't use a Cached Copy
            conn.setRequestMethod("POST");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            conn.setRequestProperty("ENCTYPE", "multipart/form-data");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=" + boundary);
            conn.setRequestProperty("userfile", fileName);

            dos = new DataOutputStream(conn.getOutputStream());

            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\";filename=\""
                    + fileName + "\"" + lineEnd);

            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            // create a buffer of  maximum size
            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();

            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // read file and write it into form...
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {

                dos.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            }

            // send multipart form data necesssary after file data...
            dos.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            dos.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
            String serverResponseMessage = conn.getResponseMessage();
            final String response;
            Log.i("uploadFile", "HTTP Response is : "
                    + serverResponseMessage + ": " + serverResponseCode + serverResponseMessage);
            String data;
            if (serverResponseCode == 200) {

                final HttpURLConnection finalConn = conn;
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {

                            /*String msg = "File Upload Completed.\n\n See uploaded file here : \n\n"
                                          +" http://www.androidexample.com/media/uploads/"
                                          +uploadFileName;*/

                        //messageText.setText(msg);
                        String data = null;
                        BufferedReader in = null;
                        try {
                            in = new BufferedReader(new
                                    InputStreamReader(
                                    finalConn.getInputStream()));
                            StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
                            String line;

                            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                                result.append(line);

                                data = result.toString();
                                break;
                            }
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }


                        Toast.makeText(Individual_Message.this, "File Upload Complete." + data,
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                });
            }

            //close the streams //
            fileInputStream.close();
            dos.flush();
            dos.close();

        } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {

            //dialog.dismiss();
            ex.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //messageText.setText("MalformedURLException Exception : check script url.");
                    Toast.makeText(Individual_Message.this, "MalformedURLException", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

            Log.e("Upload file to server", "error: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        } catch (Exception e) {

            // dialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    //  messageText.setText("Got Exception : see logcat ");
                    Toast.makeText(Individual_Message.this, "Got Exception : see logcat ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
            Log.e("Upload file", "Exception : "
                    + e.getMessage(), e);
        }
        //dialog.dismiss();
        return serverResponseCode;

    }
}
```

individually running get exact result but inside my app

get log cat like

```
    V/Selected File Path:: /storage/emulated/0/temporary_file_0.jpg
V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 268130823
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from AppMeasurementService
W/System.err: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
W/System.err:     at          android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
W/System.err:     at      libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249)
W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
W/System.err:     at  java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-    wrap0(PlainSocketImpl.java)
W/System.err:     at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:135)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.isReadable(HttpConnection.java:155)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.Connection.isReadable(Connection.java:235)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.isReadable(OkHttpClient.java:91)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:350)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
W/System.err:     at technologies.codegreen.com.drzonesample.My_Messages.Individual_Message.uploadFile(Individual_Message.java:355)
W/System.err:     at technologies.codegreen.com.drzonesample.My_Messages.Individual_Message$2.onClick(Individual_Message.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5480)
W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
E/Upload file: Exception : null
           android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
               at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1273)
               at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:249)
               at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:549)
               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:481)
               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.-wrap0(PlainSocketImpl.java)
               at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
               at com.android.okhttp.okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:135)
               at com.android.okhttp.okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:211)
               at com.android.okhttp.okio.RealBufferedSource.exhausted(RealBufferedSource.java:60)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpConnection.isReadable(HttpConnection.java:155)
               at com.android.okhttp.Connection.isReadable(Connection.java:235)
               at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.isReadable(OkHttpClient.java:91)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.createNextConnection(HttpEngine.java:350)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:340)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:330)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:248)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
               at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
               at technologies.codegreen.com.drzonesample.My_Messages.Individual_Message.uploadFile(Individual_Message.java:355)
               at technologies.codegreen.com.drzonesample.My_Messages.Individual_Message$2.onClick(Individual_Message.java:148)
               at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
               at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
               at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
               at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
               at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
               at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5480)
               at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
               at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: You are #3456 which encounters that `NetworkOnMainThreadException`.  Google for it.

Comment: And what is `individually running`?

Comment: sorry i cant understand i'm new to this please provide more information

Comment: @ greenapps file upload in app just select and upload image to server

Comment: Cannot you understand that i said that you have to google for that exception? You do not know google search?

Comment: Which file upload in which app does that?

Comment: PDF or image is uploading

Comment: This code does that? Then what is it that it does not?

Comment: That program individually make an app its working but i implemented the same code in another app getting this exception

Comment: Yes the code is pretty normal. Not to bad. Only some things you did wrong. I never saw anybody doing it the way you did it here. It is impossible that it would work in another Android app unless strict mode curses had been used. Now google for that exception and tell us how you are going to solve this problem.

Comment: i got just run the uploadFile() inside a  new Thread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                       uploadFile(Selectedpath);

                    }




                }).start();

Comment: Did you have that already or did you try to solve the exception with this thread? Very unclear.

Answer (score 0):

NetworkOnMainThreadException is thrown when your application attempts to perform networking operation on its main thread.

Use AsyncTask and run your code in it

Answer (score 0):

```
To avoid the application not responding error, android avoids you to do any long operation in UI thread synchronously. 
You have do to it in a separated thread asynchronously as follows.  

Create a different class 
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, Integer, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {
         int count = urls.length;
         long totalSize = 0;
         for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {             
//write your code of file download. 
             publishProgress((int) ((i / (float) count) * 100));
             // Escape early if cancel() is called
             if (isCancelled()) break;
         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
         setProgressPercent(progress[0]);
     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }

and in upload file method just call this. 

new DownloadFilesTask().execute(url1, url2, url3);

Theory https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html
```